# costmap_2d plugin

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-kinetic, costmap-2d, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello. I am a ROS beginner. I am doing SLAM of turtlebot 3 (waffle) in the ubuntu 16.04, ros (kinetic) personal computer environment. I modified local_costmap_params.yaml to use the costmap _ 2 d plugin (Inflation Layer). After the change, it became as follows.

local_costmap: global_frame: /odom robot_base_frame: /base_footprint

update_frequency: 10.0 publish_frequency: 10.0 transform_tolerance: 0.5

static_map: false
rolling_window: true width: 3 height: 3 resolution: 0.05
plugins: - {name: inflation_layer, type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}

However, after starting gazebo normally,

＄ export TURTLEBOT3_MODEL=waffle ＄roslaunch turtlebot3_navigation turtlebot3_navigation.launch map_file:=$HOME/map.yaml

When you do this,

Warning: Invalid argument "/map" passed to canTransform argument target_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.18/src/buffer_core.cpp

The error will come out in succession. Could I ask the reason? I feel that I am doing some fundamental mistake. Thank you.![image: this][image: plugin]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/305880/costmap_2d-plugin/) by [saito](https://answers.ros.org/users/37890/saito/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2018-10-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2018-10-29**:
Do you have a costmap_common_params.yaml file? If yes please update your answers with it.

**Comment by [saito](https://answers.ros.org/users/37890/saito/) on 2018-10-29**:
thank you.I have a costmap_common_params_waffle.yaml .this is OK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try using the following `local_costmap_params.yaml`:

```
local_costmap:
  global_frame: odom
  robot_base_frame: base_footprint
  map_type: costmap

  static_map: false
  rolling_window: true
  width: 3.0
  height: 3.0
  resolution: 0.05
  always_send_full_costmap: true

  update_frequency: 10.0
  publish_frequency: 10.0
  transform_tolerance: 0.5

  plugins:
  - {name: inflater_layer, type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}

  inflater_layer:
    inflation_radius: 0.2 # adjust the inflation for your system setup
    cost_scaling_factor: 1.0
```

The problem most probably is a TF2 thing. It does not accept leading slashes on TF2 frame names so make sure that in your common, local and global params files you dont use a "/" in the frame names

---

Originally posted by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) with karma: 1655 on 2018-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [saito](https://answers.ros.org/users/37890/saito/) on 2018-10-29**:
I did that. However, I get an error message. Also, even if you restore the same error message will appear. This error message will appear continuously.

Warning: Invalid argument "/map" passed to canTransform argument target_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like:
at line 134

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2018-10-29**:
according to your question you had something like:

```
local_costmap: 
  global_frame: /odom 
  robot_base_frame: /base_footprint
...
```

Did you try setting the frames without `"/"` so it looks like:

```
local_costmap: 
  global_frame: odom 
  robot_base_frame: base_footprint
```

**Comment by [saito](https://answers.ros.org/users/37890/saito/) on 2018-10-29**:
The same error occurs in either way. Also, reinstalling the package of turtlebot 3 will cause the same error, so it may be due to a different location somewhere.Image added.
The costmap is in error in RViz.

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2018-10-29**:
maybe it is coming from the `global_costmap_params.yaml` or  `costmap_common_params.yaml`. Check if there the frame is put with a `"/"`

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2018-10-29**:
Looks like it is a TF2 thing. It does not accept leading slashes on TF2 frame names so make sure that in your common, local and global params files you dont use a "/" in the frame names

**Comment by [saito](https://answers.ros.org/users/37890/saito/) on 2018-10-29**:
Thank you. The "/" in global was the cause.However, this image is displayed even though you do not use the plugin. Is plugin(static,obstacle,inflation) being used as a standard?

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2018-10-30**:
I am glad it fixed your initial problem. You can mark the answer as correct now by clicking the green tick. As for the plugins, the static, obstacle or inflation [layers](http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d/layered) are used as standard plugins. You can also write and implement your own custom plugin

**Comment by [saito](https://answers.ros.org/users/37890/saito/) on 2018-10-30**:
Thank you! I have made a new question about the new plugin. Please answer if you are good!